# Sobrescrita de Rota laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routing

No meu arquivo routes > web.php tenho as seguintes rotas:

```
Route::get('/user', (...));
Route::get('/user/{id}', (...) );
Route::get('/user/{id}/{nome}', (...) ); // retorna o nome e id do usuário
Route::get('/user/{id}/perfil', (...) ); // retorna o perfil do usuário
```

Quando tento acessar a ultima rota, o Laravel sempre resolve o roteamento retornando os comentários...
como eu poderia deixar o mesmo prefixo de rota com user/id porém acessando a rota referente ao perfil ?

Answer (score 3):

É só inverter as rotas, da seguinte maneira:

```
Route::get('/user', (...));
Route::get('/user/{id}', (...) );
Route::get('/user/{id}/perfil', (...) ); // retorna o perfil do usuário
Route::get('/user/{id}/{nome}', (...) ); // retorna o nome e id do usuário
```

Comment: Agradeço ! irei tentar André! :D ; -
Então as rotas com "parâmetros" devo sempre chamar depois após?

Comment: Isso Kasio, tem que chamar depois senão vai sempre entender como parâmetro.

Comment: Problema resolvido?

Comment: Sim! obrigado andré!

Comment: Que ótimo, não se esquece de colocar a resposta com a correta, pra ajudar os outros no futuro.

Answer (score 3):

Olá, Kasio!

Se você tiver rotas semelhantes, porém que receba parâmetros, as que recebem devem vir por último.

E você também pode agrupar essas rotas em um grupo de rotas, deixando-as mais "limpas", e menos repetitivas:

Exemplo:

```
<?php
//...
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'controller@method'); // Rota: /user
    Route::get('/{id}', 'controller@method'); // Rota: /user/{id}
    Route::get('/{id}/perfil', 'controller@method'); // Rota: /user/{id}/perfil
    Route::get('/{id}/{nome}', 'controller@method'); // Rota: /user/{id}/{nome}
});
```